# React read file added in dist folder after deploy

Tags: json, reactjs, azure-pipelines

Background: I have a React application that is published from a pipeline in Azure, in the pipeline the React project is compiled and I add a extra `settings.json` file that includes keys and such that I get through a service in the pipeline (I get the keys from Key Vault from Azure portal). And I end up with this after publish:

[image]

So the question is how can I import the values from a file that is located in the dist folder? And how can I add a similar file that I can use while I develop and where should it be located? I need these keys for api calls, and after I publish I need to get the values from the new file located outside the compiled code in the dist folder. Note that with pipeline I dont want to have two paths that I switch between while developing and publishing, I need a path that will work for booth files.

The key values can change between all deploys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a file and but in the dist folder through the pipeline, this file allows me to open json files from mysite.com/settings.json (which contains my keys)

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
     </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And I also have a settings.json file in the dist folder also created through the pipeline.

So now I can get the file from a api call or a local dev file with this code added

```
import * as Settings from '../../../settings.json'
...
@action initKeys = () => {
    if(window.location.origin.includes("localhost"))
        this.keys = new keyModel(Settings)        
    else //calling api mysite.com/settings.json to get the file
        new AzSearchService(this.keys).getSettingsFile().then((response: any) => runInAction(() => this.keys = new keyModel(response)))                       
}
```

So the final structure looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly. Below Kudu api might be what you are looking for. When you successfully published your application in Azure, you can visit `https://yourappsitename.scm.azurewebsites.net` to manage your deployment contents.

You can also use Kudu api to manipulate files and folders of your application in azure.

Below powershell scripts shows how to get a file of your application in azure.

```
$srcResGroupName = "Test"
$srcWebAppName = "tstest12"

# Get publishing profile for SOURCE application
$srcWebApp = Get-AzWebApp -Name $srcWebAppName -ResourceGroupName $srcResGroupName
[xml]$publishingProfile = Get-AzWebAppPublishingProfile -WebApp $srcWebApp
# Create Base64 authorization header
$username = $publishingProfile.publishData.publishProfile[0].userName
$password = $publishingProfile.publishData.publishProfile[0].userPWD

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))

$apiBaseUrl = "https://$($srcWebApp.Name).scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/settings.json"

# Download the settings.json file to ./settings.json

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$apiBaseUrl" `
                    -Headers @{UserAgent="powershell/1.0"; `
                     Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} `
                    -Method GET `
                    -OutFile ./settings.json
```

Above script will download the settings.json file from the server and save it to a pointed place. Above scripts get the username and password with scripts, you can also get them in the publish profile by going to the Overview blade on your App Service, clicking ...More at the top of the blade, and then clicking Get publish profile

If you run above script in a powershell task in build pipeline. You can save the file to a place on the agent(find the path and its mapping to [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)) and consume it in the following tasks.

Below is an example to add a file to the application server. It use the same Authorization as above scripts.

```
$filePath = "c:\temp\settings.json";
$apiUrl = "https://$($srcWebApp.Name).scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/settings1.json";
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -UserAgent $userAgent -Method PUT -InFile $filePath -ContentType "application/json";
```

For more usage of Kudu api you can check [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploy-to-azure-platform-as-a-service-websites-using-kudu-rest-apis/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Azure powershell in your devOps pipeline using the script below -

```
function Get-AzWebAppPublishingCredentials($resourceGroupName, $webAppName, $slotName = $null) {
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($slotName) -or $slotName.ToLower() -eq "production") {
        $resourceType = "Microsoft.Web/sites/config"
        $resourceName = "$webAppName/publishingcredentials"
    }
    else {
        $resourceType = "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config"
        $resourceName = "$webAppName/$slotName/publishingcredentials"
    }
    $publishingCredentials = Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType $resourceType -ResourceName $resourceName -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
    return $publishingCredentials
}

function Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue($resourceGroupName, $webAppName, $slotName = $null) {
    $publishingCredentials = Get-AzWebAppPublishingCredentials $resourceGroupName $webAppName $slotName
    $ret = @{ }
    $ret.header = ("Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingUserName, $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingPassword))))
    $ret.url = $publishingCredentials.Properties.scmUri
    return $ret
}

function Get-FileFromWebApp($resourceGroupName, $webAppName, $slotName = "", $kuduPath) {
    $KuduAuth = Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue $resourceGroupName $webAppName $slotName
    $kuduApiAuthorisationToken = $KuduAuth.header
    $kuduApiUrl = $KuduAuth.url + "/api/vfs/$kuduPath"

    Write-Host " Downloading File from WebApp. Source: '$kuduApiUrl'." -ForegroundColor DarkGray
    $tmpPath = "$($env:TEMP)\$([guid]::NewGuid()).json"
    $null = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $kuduApiUrl `
        -Headers @{"Authorization" = $kuduApiAuthorisationToken; "If-Match" = "*" } `
        -Method GET `
        -ContentType "application/json" `
        -OutFile $tmpPath
    $ret = (Get-Content $tmpPath) | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
    Remove-Item $tmpPath -Force
    return $ret
}

$jsonFile=Get-FileFromWebApp "<resource group name>" "<web app name>" "" "site/wwwroot/<path to json file>"
$value = $jsonFile.value
Write-Host "The value from file is ::" $value
```